# Can't login after yesterday's update

Tags: display, greeter, drivers

I boot up today and tried to login. I can't do it on the main account or guest account.

I updated the OS yesterday. But I have not installed any program recently.

I'm using the Nvidia drivers on my Latitude E6510

How can I solve this.

[image: only thing that I can access.]

Answer (score 1):

Same problem with an Nvidia graphic card (GeForce 210). After an update, I couldn't login to the main account. After some research and trying different things, this solved it for me:

When you are in the login screen, enter the terminal by pressing ctrl+alt+f1 and then:

```
sudo apt-get remove bumblebee
sudo apt-get remove nvidia*
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo ubuntu-drivers list
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

Reboot

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Same here.

Do you use plymouth splash screen for decrypting Luks at boot?

If yes, there seems to be a bug since years.

With the update came drivers for nvidia. If installed if have the same.

Try booting in recovery mode then luks passward can be entered in textmode.

Try deinstalling the nivida drivers in AppCenter